# How to show Menu programmatically in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I need to expand menu by some event in Swift UI. How can this be done?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var openMenu = false
    var body: some View {
        Menu("Options") {
            Button("Order Now", action: placeOrder)
            Button("Adjust Order", action: adjustOrder)
            Button("Cancel", action: cancelOrder)
        }
    }

    func placeOrder() { }
    func adjustOrder() { }
    func cancelOrder() { }
}
```

For example, when openMenu variable changes, the menu expands

Comment: I am Not sure what you want to do, can you explain

Comment: how do you want it to expand?

Comment: The Menu struct isn’t the correct data struct in this case, try an alert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean you want to make the menu appear on-screen, you cannot do that in pure SwiftUI as of 2021.

UIKit has [`showMenu(from:rect:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenucontroller/3044217-showmenu), and AppKit has [`popUpContextMenu(_:with:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenu/1518170-popupcontextmenu), but SwiftUI has no API to show a menu programmatically.

In SwiftUI 2021, you can use [`confirmationDialog(_:isPresented:titleVisibility:presenting:actions:message:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/confirmationdialog(_:ispresented:titlevisibility:presenting:actions:message:)-8y541) or the deprecated [`ActionSheet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/actionsheet#) type to present something menu-like.