# Programmatically controled Floating List (like drop-down list) with Swift

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

I'm developing an app with SwiftUI for macOS, during which I need a floating list (e.g. the list box of drop-down list, `Picker` and `Menu` in SwiftUI, as shown in the screenshot below). Also it should be showed and hidden programmatically.

In summary, I need a list view which:

1. Have the `Picker` list box behavior:

   - Auto hide list when I click other place.
   - Don't need a hard-coded height. It can fit the height of list content. When the height of content is higher that the full screen, it turns into a scroll list.
2. Hide and show by code.
3. Control selection indicator (that blue row background) with code. For example, "up-arrow" and "down-arrow" to select, and "enter" to select.

[image]

### First Trying: SwiftUI Native Controls

According to this post [How to show Menu programmatically in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69822148/how-to-show-menu-programmatically-in-swiftui). There's no suitable Views, and I cannot find one also.

Showing list in `Picker` and `Menu` need clicking on the button, which cannot be controlled programmatically. The suggested `.confirmationDialog`, like an Alert view, is totally not in my case.

### Second Trying: `.overlay{}`

```swift
Text("Click Me")
    .onTapGesture { isPresented.toggle() }
    .overlay {
        if isPresented {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(1..<30) {
                        Text("#\($0)")
                    }
                }
            }
            //.frame(height: 300)    // must set height
        }
    }
```

However the list won't get out of the size of parent view unless I hard-code a height for it.

### Third Trying: `.popover`

```swift
@State var selection: Int = 0

Text("Selection: \(selection)")
    .onTapGesture {
        isPresented.toggle()
    }
    .popover(isPresented: $isPresented, arrowEdge: .bottom) {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(0..<30, id: \.self) { num in
                    Button {
                        selection = num
                        isPresented = false
                    } label: {
                        Text("#\(num)")
                    }
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                }
            }
            
        }
        .scrollIndicators(.never)
        .buttonStyle(MenuButtonStyle())
        .padding(4)
        
    }
```

Better, but have some problems, it couldn't be better if they can be solved:

1. List is going to get out of the computer screen, it turns into a scroll list. However, there's no arrow indicator visually telling you can scroll down. (The expected result is shown in screenshot below)
2. The animation and indicator arrow of popover view is annoying, and I found no way to remove them in SwiftUI.

[image]

### Fourth Trying: Asking other Frameworks for Help

I'm searching some solutions from other UI framework like `AppKit`, but I only have experience with SwiftUI, not so familiar with others. I cannot find the suitable view.

Sincerely looking forward to your help! :)